# p5js no longer gives access to URLSearchParams; is there a way to retrieve them from a shared p5j3 sketch?

Tags: p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/psb_david_petty/full/gblbwpq7g?m=MSG

Did [p5.js](http://p5js.org/) do something to their share links (a redirect or something?) so that `URLSearchParams` can no longer retrieve the parameters? This code returns always `null`:

```
  let uri = new URL(window.location.href);
  let msg = uri.searchParams.get('m');
```

[p5.js](http://p5js.org/) recently started to include a red p5* banner at the top of shared links and URI search parameters are no longer readable. I have have looked on the 'net and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=p5js) for answers and I have tried this on four different browsers. What worked before has recently stopped working.

Is there a way to set variables / parameters in an `iframe` embedded with a shared [p5.js](http://p5js.org/) sketch so they are available to the code? Thanks!

— psb_david_petty

Comment: I must be missing something, are you using an `iframe` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

[A change](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-web-editor/issues/1965) was recently made to p5js.org that eliminates the banner-less full screen preview of a p5.js sketch created with editor.p5js.org. This change was made because somebody was abusing the site to phish credentials. As a result, sketches hosted with either p5js.org or OpenProcessing.org will actually be iframes within iframes, so any URL parameters that you specify will be lost.

The obvious solution is to host your sketch somewhere that you have more control over how it is served. For example you could host it on https://replit.com/