# Try to remove p5*js title

Tags: html, p5.js

I have a portfolio site that I used in p5.js, and this ad appears above me. Is there an option to cancel it?

[image: sketch screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

the way is solved this was by hosting the p5 code on my website. This removes the banner completely. However if you want to have more than 1 canvas you should take a look at the link below. To position each canvas where you want use the id selector in css to position it.

https://editor.p5js.org/caminofarol/sketches/r609C2cs

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32402357)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "ad", but a banner meant to clearly identify the page as being something hosted on p5js.org. As I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050668/p5js-no-longer-gives-access-to-urlsearchparams-is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-them/70070854#70070854)

> [A change](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-web-editor/issues/1965) was recently made to p5js.org that eliminates the banner-less full screen preview of a p5.js sketch created with editor.p5js.org. This change was made because somebody was abusing the site to phish credentials.

For the time being you can still use https://openprocessing.org/ to host sketches such that you can embed them with no banner (however there's no guarantee this won't change in the future). If you want full control of how your sketches look when you embed them on another page I suggest you host the content of your sketch on your own server.

Comment: Something like https://codepen.io/ might work well too.